# php container keeps restarting using docker-compose

Tags: php, linux, docker, apache, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file.  When I try to up the file the mysql container start, but the php one keeps on restarting.  When I look at the logs all I get is "interactive shell" constantly.  Any idea why this is happening?

```
---
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: php:alpine3.12
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - web_Data:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Password1
    volumes:
      - mariadb_Data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
volumes:
  web_Data:
  mariadb_Data:
    driver: local
```

Comment: Can you paste the logs of `web` service, please?

Comment: All I keep getting is exactly what I put on the description "Interactive Shell" constantly in detached mode.  without the -d I get "exited with code 0" on line 1, then "Interactive shell" on line2 and the cycle repeats.

Answer (score 5):

The reason you are getting `Interactive shell` message it's because that's an output of `php:alpine3.12` image and since your container is constantly restarting, it keeps logging that message.

I don't really know PHP but it looks like the command that the image tries to do is `docker-php-entrypoint php -a`, and that starts an interactive shell, am I right?

If that is the case, then you need to run it in *interactive mode*. To do that, in `docker-compose.yml` file, just add the last 2 lines:

```yaml
web:
    image: php:alpine3.12
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - web_Data:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Then your container will keep running and you will be able to interact with it.

Comment: That worked.  When I put the two lines.  The server is now running.  Thanks,

Comment: Great! Glad to help. I would appreciate if you accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are using an inappropriate PHP image.  If you want to run PHP with a web server then you should use one of:

- `php:<version>-fpm`
- `php:<version>-apache`

See [Image Variants](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) in the Docker documentation.